# How do you pronounce Erjie?

Tags: pronunciation

I have an interview and the interviewer's name is Erjie. I'd like to be able to pronounce when I get there. Can anyone give me guidance on how to pronounce his name?

FWIW, the person is from Singapore.

Comment: You can make a rough guess, but will never get an 100%-sure answer. Because Latin letter's pronunciation depends on the context, you didn't even give what language that name is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this person's name is spelt according to standard Mandarin Pinyin.

- **[jie]** is pronounced something like "jyeh".
- **[er]**, in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), is **/ˀɤɻ/**, made up of the [close-mid back unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_unrounded_vowel) and the [retroflex approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_approximant). Speaking for an American English audience,

  - A fair approximation of the close-mid back unrounded vowel is IPA **/o/**, which is the vowel in the English word "g**o**".
  - The retroflex approximant can be given as the consonant in the English word "**r**ed". See http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_075_red.htm and listen to "Standard American".

Putting this together, and ignoring the tones, you should be pronouncing the name like the following:

- **[er]** - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8AOX0FssQk
- **[jie]** - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m6bQVJtPT8

(The sound plays at about 4 seconds in both videos.)

Comment: 尔杰？类似于 情深深雨蒙蒙 的 陆尔杰？ 很老式的名字

Comment: Maybe. I’m only giving a toneless guess assuming it’s mandarin. It might not be chinese at all but...